# Is there a way to exclude a service from being executed with one specific profile in Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Suppose I have a Docker Compose file similar to this:

```yaml
services:
  serviceA:
    image: imageA

  serviceB:
    image: imageB

  serviceC:
    image: imageC
    profile:
      - debug

  serviceB-debug:
    image: imageB
    depends_on:
      - serviceC
    profile:
      - debug
```

And the behavior I would like is:

- If I do not specify anything (e.g., when I run `docker compose up`), run `serviceA` and `serviceB`.
- If I enable `debug` profile, run `serviceA`, `serviceC` and **only once this is started**, `serviceB-debug`, which is the same as `serviceB` but with the dependency I mention.

So, for **all profiles** I would like to run `serviceA` (done); for `debug` profile, `serviceA`, `serviceC` and `serviceB-debug` (done); and for **all profiles except `debug`**, `serviceB` (the problem is here).

Is there a way to tell `serviceB` to **do not** run when I select the `debug` profile? Or, as alternative, is there a way to add that `depends_on` condition to `serviceB` only when I enable `debug` profile?

I have searched in Compose documentation and different sites but I could not find anything for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can split current docker-compose.yml to docker-compose.yml and docker-compose.debug.yml and then run basic setup as before:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

And debug version with:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.debug.yml up -d
```

More info: [docker-compose extends](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/)

For profiles, you would need to add some "other" profile and mark serviceB (non-debug) with that. [docker-compose profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) do not seem to have an option to disable service in profile (something like "!debug").

Comment: Thanks. I have considered this option previously as an alternative to using profiles, but I would prefer to have a single Compose file and make the normal use more _transparent_ for the user (so user just would have to execute a `docker compose up`). I have also considered adding a `default` profile to the services I would like to run in general and using a `DOCKER_COMPOSE_PROFILE=default` variable to hide it from user's point of view, but it does not seem to work, do you know why?

Comment: According to https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/ variable name is "COMPOSE_PROFILE" not "DOCKER_COMPOSE_PROFILE".